# How to get the current screen lock info?

Tags: android, locking, screen, screen-lock

I have an app which allows to remotely lock other phones named "Parental Lock".

In the app, users can put a password for a time to their "children"s phone.

The problem is when the time specified by the "parent" ends, I want to remove the password given by the "parent" and restore the original one if there was.

For now, when the time ends, I am removing the password via device manager from the phone but to restore the old password put by the user itself long before, I must get the password info.

Answer (score 0):

The get the password, the password itself had to be encrypted in first place (with yet another password, brr).

And the rule #1 says: never ever encrypt passwords, use hashing algorithms with a salt to store them.

Comment: but I need to get the password which user set via settings on his/her phone, not the passwords which are put by my app.

Comment: google knows this rule and also hash passwords. trust me. that's why there is now way to get them. sorry.

Comment: So you say even if I got the device admin permission, it is impossible to get the password. I see, thx.